# Approximating probability space with a symmetric one

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Is there any general result showing that any probability space can be "approximated" (in some reasonable sense) with a *symmetric* probability space? A consequence of such result would be a kind of transference principle saying that, roughly speaking, any statement involving probabilities of unions and intersections that is true in a symmetric space, holds true in fact in *any* space.

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetric probability space"?

Comment: @D.Thomine: one with the sample space finite, the $\sigma$-algebra being the power set of the sample space, and the uniform probability measure.